# Convert JPG to A4 PDF without white space on top with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to convert JPGs documents of varying sizes to A4 paper.
(photos of documents taken from the NextCloud Android App "scan document" function). But the problem is also reproduceable with this cat picture below.

I tried

`convert -page A4  -background white in.jpg out.pdf`

but this leaves me with a white space at the top of the page.

I would prefer that the jpg is aligned on top.

[image: Output 11]

`convert -page A4 -gravity north -background white in.jpg out.pdf`

But now I basically get a fully white page.

When opening the file in Inkscape, I realize that the input is placed somewhere out of the page.

[image: Output 2]

What is going wrong here?

EDIT as per comment:

`convert -page A4 -gravity north -background white +repage cat-stairs.jpg /tmp/out.pdf` does not work - maybe it's really a but, adding the original jpg for reference.

[Original input JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsO8P.jpg)

Version info:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

Comment: What about adding `+repage`?

Comment: I would do that with Latex instead of ImageMagick. Latex produces a PDF, so the results is what you want. Here is the solution using Latex https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136900/insert-a-full-page-image.

Comment: Also, check out [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) in Python, which is probably in your distribution. It does lossless conversion of jpegs.

Comment: img2pdf complained about the alpha channel which the NextCloud app produces ... but sure, I could remove that first

Answer (score 2):

> What is going wrong here?

A bug, far as I can tell.

---

ImageMagick probably isn't the right tool here.

Generally, ImageMagick's `convert` is often a catch-all solution, but as often the slowest possible solution and ImageMagick might single-handedly be the library with the most exploited remote code execution vulnerabilities on servers in existence, so maybe at least look to its sibling, GraphicsMagick, which is less memory-hungry.

In this very specific case, it's desirable to not use either, as they basically take any kind of input file, render it to a bitmap in memory, and then save the bitmap as the specified output file format.

In your special use case, PDF is perfectly capable of embedding a JPEG file. None of that lossy recompression should be done. So: don't!

@nobody's comment is very useful, in short, you write a text file with the content:

Save it as `magicpage`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
infile="$1"

fname="$(mktemp --suffix=.tex magicpage.XXXXX)"
>"${fname}" print -R '
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  placement=top,
  scale=1,
  angle=0,
  opacity=1,
  contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{\imagename}}
}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\,
\end{document}
'
pdflatex -jobname "${infile:r}" "\\def\\imagename{${infile}}\\input{${fname}}" > /dev/null
```

then, make it executable using `chmod 755 /path/to/magicpage`. You can now run `/path/to/magicpage yourimage.jpg` and get a `yourimage.pdf` in the same directory.